# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string [The error disappear with top (xxxx)]

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

**Environment:**

- SQL Server 14 Express on Ubuntu 16.04
- SQL Server Management Studio v 17.4

I observed a very wearied question but I believe there is an explanation. When I attempted to run the following SQL command:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  
    (SELECT 
         CONVERT(DATE, clinicaldate, 6) AS NEWDATE, 
         [id], 
         [DateCreated] ... 
     FROM
         myDatabase) t1 
WHERE  
    t1.newdate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/09/2015', 103) 
                   AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '30/09/2015', 103)
```

I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'convert'

However, if I use `top (XXX)` in `select`, everything works fine. Please notice that the total record is less than 500000, which means I actually select all of them.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  
    (SELECT TOP(500000) 
         CONVERT(DATE, clinicaldate, 6) AS NEWDATE, 
         [id], 
         [DateCreated] ... 
     FROM
         myDatabase) t1 
WHERE  
    t1.newdate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/09/2015', 103) 
                   AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '30/09/2015', 103)
```

Comment: Your syntax correct.  Probably you have an invalid char in your query, but you can not see it because of management studio cannot understand it. And you can use `top(100) percent`  instead of top(500000).

Comment: By `SQL Server 14` - do you mean SQL Server **2014** or do you mean SQL Server **2017** (which would be v14.x.x.x) ..... please be clearer on this

Comment: No, something else is changed between the two. Adding `TOP(50000)` will not correct a *syntax* error elsewhere in a query. Unfortunately, you've elided details. And the error message in your *title* is not one that is reported as a syntax error. So it's difficult to pull things apart from this question because it's **inconsistent**.

Comment: can you try to select top (all rows count) what will be the result?

Comment: @marc_s: It is SQL Server 14 Express and I access that via SQL Management Studio 17.

Comment: You're still **not any clearer** than before.... do you mean SQL Server **2014** (v12), or do you mean SQL Server **v14** (= SQL Server 2017) - what does running `SELECT @@Version` return??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an invalid date in the column.  It is not in the rows chosen when you use `top`, so the problem is rare.

Don't use `convert()` on constants.  Just use:

```
WHERE  t1.newdate BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2015-09-30'
```

Easier to write and read.  (One caveat:  There is one internationalization setting where you need to drop the hyphens).

Then, find the problematic dates using `try_convert()`:

```
select clinicaldate
from t
where try_convert(DATE, clinicaldate, 6) is null;
```

You can fix your data error by using `try_convert()` rather than `convert()`, but it is better to fix the data.

Comment: Thanks for your great comments. It is caused by one record in which no valid date exists.